# Retrieve keyring username on python

Tags: python, python-keyring

I have got keyring concept. And I'm trying to get the username list from it.

Unfortunately it seems there is no function for get saved username list.

I hope to show the saved list and choose one for auto logging.

Even though there is credential, it shows only at least username.

If there is no function about it, I will make to username list when login info is saved.

But I don't want it purely. Is there any library for saving data like keyring mechanism?

(encoding and saving private region each machine, but without password. Only String like username)

Comment: You can use this library: https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Comment: Thanks for your help. And I checked the library. Unfortunately, the library doesn't support any function to get username list. Even though there is some function like get_credential(), but it shows only at least saved information. So I'm trying to find some library which is support to encode, save and return enumeration of saved string.